# Share node.js Module Between Web Worker and Website on Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, deployment

I have a node.js site deployed as a website on Azure. It has several web jobs which are stored in /root/App_Data/Jobs/...

Is it possible to share code/custom modules between the website and jobs? or does the code have to be duplicated in each directory?

Answer (score 1):

A node.js app can use `require()` to load its code from any path.  So, you can use a path to a shared location if that makes sense to your implementation.

For deployment reasons, it may be easier though to actually use two separate copies of the code.  Then, you can test and release each component separately.  If they both use a shared location, you can't update one without affecting the other so both have to be tested and released on the changed code at exactly the same time.